# New Stack Snippets design requires more horizontal scrolling through code

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, code-formatting, stack-snippets

I can't see the new Stack Snippet layout as an improvement. The window is now narrower, with wasted space around it, making it harder to format code to not require horizontal scrolling, especially if you want to add comments after lines of code.
 (I often try to make sure my code and comments fit the window width; I imagine other people do as well. I want to make it easy to see the code at a glance.)

Please consider changing this back to at least optimise the width of the snippet.

(Btw, this probably also affects html/css or html5 canvas examples which have been sized to the Snippet output window.)

---

[image: Stack Snippet screenshot]

Comment: So, is this a discussion, or a feature request? It looks more like a bug report. Please pick the proper tag.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, the behaviour is by design, so I guess it's a discussion.

Comment: @m69: It *may* be by design. Or it could be a side-effect of an unrelated change and no one noticed the effect on snippets before pushing it. I'd tag it either [tag:bug] or [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It seems to be part of a major overhaul of the Snippets feature. But the [bug] tag is for "mistakes, malfunctions and programming errors", and I consider this to be a mistake.

Comment: I don't think it is related to a major overhaul, actually. (I agree it's a bug.) The big work in snippets was a few weeks back. This just appears to be some CSS tweaking gone wrong (such as [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326042/157247) where padding was added they clearly didn't mean to add and created a bug, now thankfully fixed).

Comment: Stack Snippets now have [20px of padding](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTngz.png). Every time I see a snippet now it feels like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nNndr.png). Just reduce the padding to something near 8px and you'd get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cxDOR.png).

Comment: @j08691 I assume it was decided that snippets should visually stand out from regular code blocks, but they should have chosen a different background colour or something else that doesn't mess with the usability. There's no good reason to give snippets less than the maximum width.

Comment: I added the following CSS, which incorporates the padding suggestion from @j08691, and a box-shadow to make it pop just a little bit more: `.snippet-code {
    padding: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}`

Comment: In my opinion the code boxes were already too small before the extra margin was introduced. I think it should be an option (e.g. using a button) to change the layout so the sidebar can be closed and code can expand over the entire width of the page.

Comment: There is a Meta SE post on the update where you can talk about this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280250/stack-snippets-upgrade-new-ui

Comment: @m69 Right, I'm not saying you have to go there with your issue, I only said you *can*.

Comment: @TylerH Sorry about that, I was a bit irritated by something completely unrelated to SO or this discussion when I wrote that.

Comment: I like the new design.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Well, it's not ugly or even too narrow in itself. But the padding on the side doesn't really do anything; it just puts whitespace between content and more whitespace, so I see no good reason for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. The padding for the snippet box has been reduced... and while I was at it, I have added a new feature that I hope you will like:

[image]

This new *Expand snippet* link will make the snippet to appear full screen, this way you can make it arbitrarily wide by just adjusting the size of your browser window. The *Full screen* link for the results will still appear and work as usual (but not when the snippet is expanded, of course).

Comment: I don't want to seem ungrateful, but is there a chance of just removing the whitespace on the sides altogether? It doesn't seem to serve any purpose. It's just there between the snippet and more whitespace.

Comment: Alternatively, to preserve the padding, expand the box outside of the question container.

Answer (score -13):

A quick eye count of the number of characters fitting in the code block comes to 83, which comfortably fits the [old standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100).

A dissenting view: Why is that code snippet so dang wide?

The ability to organize code in columns side by side is a feature of good line-length limitations, and [its presence as a default in linters](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len) speaks to that. Having a snippet next to an editor window, or multiple columns of code visible is a huge asset in comparing code (and it's certainly better than [copy-pasting blindly from SO](http://qz.com/679084/nissan-developers-copied-code-from-the-internet-pasted-it-into-a-remote-access-app/)). (Not all of us can afford nice wide monitors like [the SO remote employees](http://readwrite.com/2015/02/24/stack-exchange-remote-employees/) ;)

---

Personally I think you are right to bring up the issue, however, and @Midas is also right to give users a *choice* with a button.

Comment: The thing is that thousands of bits of code were formatted (and probably also html/css examples and html5 canvas elements) with the size of the snippet window in mind, and reducing the size now messes with that effort and risks making those answers less clear. I'm not particularly in favour of any specific width, it's just unnecessary to change it for no real reason other than the whim of a graphical designer.